# REST - PUT and newly introduced field

Tags: rest, put, http-method

This is a followup of [an older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62229223/rest-does-the-put-method-have-to-remove-an-optional-field-when-it-is-omitted).

I have a resource `Car` which have fields `plate` and `color`.

We have a REST client updating all the fields of the car:

```
PUT /cars/:id
{
  plate: "ABC-1234",
  color: "black"
}
```

Now we extend the API and add a new field `owner`. It's a field we already have in the DB, we have just decided to add it to the API. The question is, how the PUT request should behave. There are the following options:

1. If we want to do it by [the book](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) we have to make the `owner` field mandatory on the PUT and either break all existing clients or release a new version. In other words, field addition is not a backward compatible change. That means it's expensive to start small and add more fields when needed.
2. Make the field optional and thus breaking the rules. Moreover, the API will be strange, all the original fields will be mandatory, all the fields that were added later will be optional.
3. Do not try to implement PUT as it's clearly impossible to do it right and use only PATCH

This all gets more complicated when the newly added filed is in fact optional. How can we unset it?

a) We can distinguish between missing field and explicitly set null. If the client explicitly sets the field to null we reset it, if the filed is missing from the payload, we keep the original value. While it's possible to implement, it's not something I have seen in a real API and it is not supported out of the box in most typed languages.

b) Use an empty string or other special value to unset the field value.

This seems too complex for something as basic as modifying a value. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

> If we want to do it by the book

1. That's an old book - the [IANA method registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-methods/http-methods.xhtml) will tell you where to find the [current book](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-semantics#section-9.3.4).
2. You are mis-interpreting the book.

> The request method token is the primary source of request semantics

Note: semantics, not implementation.  The standard defines how the request should be interpreted, but it does not constrain the implementation.

```
PUT /cars/:id
Content-Type: application/json

{
  plate: "ABC-1234",
  color: "black"
}
```

The meaning of the request is "make your representation of the resource look like the one I've included in the request".  But it is explicit in the definition of PUT that the server may need to transform the provided representation into a form that is consistent with the configured constraints of the resource.

(Note: you do have to be a little bit careful in your response not to imply that you accepted the requested representation unchanged.)

Therefore, introducing "owner" as an optional field in the schema is a perfectly reasonable thing to do.

> This all gets more complicated when the newly added field is in fact optional.

Yes.  You'll probably want to review the [lessons learned in the design of XML schema](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70075703/54734).